# How do I format ter print statement to where Count, Sum, And average have the number below instead of beside them as provided the the comment

Tags: python, printing, formatting

```
Sum = 0
Count = 0
while True:
    data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")
    if data == "":
        break
    Sum += float(data) #ever
    Count += 1
    print("Count",Count,"Sum",Sum,"Average", Sum / Count) # This statement is the one I need the solution, when printed it comes to side to side need it as the comment has it below I don't know exactly how to align it 
print("-"*38)      
print("The sum is", Sum / Count)
if Count > 0:
    print("The average is", Sum / Count) #how to align this statement?


# Thank you!
#Count          Sum     Average
#4           335.00       83.75
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you want to save all your user `inputs` and `Sum, Count, Avg`... into a `list` first then print at once when all done?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you three suggestions (code samples may follow):

1. f-string (python format string)
2. columnar  (library for printing tabular data)
3. column -t (shell program for formatting output)

Addendum:  Now that I've read your code more closely, I see that it's interactive.  Since it's interactive, `column -t` is out, since the prompts to the user will also be formatted.  `columnar` is also not such a great way to go either, because it is typically provided a list of lists to format.  That leaves you python format string (f-string or format() statement).

Here's an approach for printing using python format strings:

```
Sum = 0
Count = 0
while True:
    data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")
    if data == "":
        break
    Sum += float(data) #ever
    Count += 1

    print("%-10s %10s %10s" % ("Count","Sum","Average") )
    print("%-10d %10.2f %10.2f" % (Count,Sum,Sum/Count) )

print("-"*38)      
print("The sum is", Sum )
if Count > 0:
    print("The average is", Sum / Count) #how to align this statement?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("{:>15} {: >15} {: >15}\n{:>15} {: >15} {: >15}\n".format("Count","Sum","Average",Count,Sum,Sum/Count))
```

Output:

```
      Count             Sum         Average
        400              30              20
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Sum = 0
Count = 0
while True:
    data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")
    if data == "":
        break
    Sum += float(data) #ever
    Count += 1
    Avg = Sum/Count

    print(f"Count\t{'Sum'.rjust(len(str(Sum)))}\t{'Average'.rjust(len(str(Avg)))}")
    print(f"{Count:>5}\t{str(Sum).rjust(len(str(Sum)))}\t{str(Avg).rjust(len(str(Sum/Count)))}")
    # sdfsdfsd
print("-"*38)
print("The sum is", Sum / Count)
if Count > 0:
    print("The average is", Sum / Count) #how to align this statement?
```